# How to test my model method Project.all()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec

How to test my `model` method `Project.all()`. I get a list of `Projects` when i query my method, but i am not sure on what to text against it?.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Project do

  before(:all) do

  end

  it "get all projects" do 
    projects = Project.all( authorization: @token)
  end

end
```

My question is what do i **check against it to pass this test**?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below :-

```
describe Project do
  # use the mandatory attributes while creating the Project objects.
  # I assumed, there is a :name attribute defined. But this is an idea
  # about the approach.

  let!(:proj1) { Project.create(name: "a", authorization: @token) }
  let!(:proj2) { Project.create(name: "b", authorization: @token) }
  let!(:proj3) { Project.create(name: "c", authorization: @token1) }

  after(:all) { Project.delete_all }

  it "get all projects" do 
    expect(Project.all( authorization: @token)).to match_array([proj1, proj2])
  end
end
```

Comment: What if the user already contains some projects, coz i am hitting a rest based service... so have no control.

Comment: @Mathew Why are you hitting original DB. That's how we don't test.

Comment: What does the after block do?

Comment: @Mathew See this - https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks

Comment: by default is it after(:each) or after(:all)

Comment: @Mathew `after(:each)`.. sorry I also forgot

Comment: In My application, where can i see the test database configured?

Comment: @Mathew Look [1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database) and [2](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-database-setup.htm) and [3](http://blog.nistu.de/2012/03/25/multi-database-setup-with-rails-and-rspec)

Comment: Since i am hitting a rest based service, what should i ask my API team for?